# check proof if a sequence is decreasing and bounded is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

My question was  Prove, using the ε-characterisation of a limit, that a sequence $(a_n)_{n≥1}$ of real numbers which is bounded below and decreasing is convergent. You may assume that a set of real numbers which is bounded below has an infimum.

I wrote if a sequence of real numbers is decreasing and bounded below, then the infimum is the limit.

We prove if $A=\left\{a_n,n\in\mathbb N^\ast\right\}$ is bounded below then it is convergent and the limit is $c=\inf_{n\ge 1}\left\{a_n\right\}$.

Since $A$ is a non-empty and bounded below subset of $\mathbb R$, $c$ is the greatest lower bound  of $A$ if it satisfies

1. $c$ is a lower bound of $A$,
2. for all $k\in\mathbb R$, if $k$ is a lower bound for $A$, then $k\le c$.

Now for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb N^\ast$ such that $a_N<c+\epsilon$ since otherwise $c+\epsilon$ is an lower bound which contradicts c being the infimum of $A$.

Then since $(a_n)$ is decreasing, for $n\ge N$ we have $a_N\ge a_n$, so: $$c-\epsilon < c\le a_n\le a_N < c+\epsilon$$

We see for $n\ge N$, $c-\epsilon < a_n< c+\epsilon$ and so $\left|a_n−c\right|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=c$, that is $(a_n)$ is convergent to $c$.

I modified the proof from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Proof  can someone check if I did it right please

Comment: Now for every ε>0 there exists N such that AN [did u forget to complete the sentence?]

please use $\in$ [\in] to show inclusion.

Comment: Also the converging theorem contains for all epsilon there exist N such that for every N<m ... you need to show that.

Comment: I have changed the first bit. Im not sure how to do the second bit

Comment: "Now for every ε>0 there exists N such that AN< c+ε since otherwise c+ε is an lower bound which contradicts c being the infimum of {An}" So u have that $A_N<C+\varepsilon$ your conclusion from it is correct but not relevant to the question. Try changing the conclusion so it suits "for all N<m ..." statement from the limit theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but I don't really know how to do that at all.

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that if $(A_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing and bounded sequence of real numbers then $(A_n)$ is converging:

Theorem: $A_n$ will be called converging to limit $L\in\mathbb R$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that [complete it...]

Given $A_n$ is bounded and decreasing there exists $c\in\mathbb R$ it infimum [largest lower bound]

Claim: c satisfies the Limit Theorem

proof: c is a lower limit so for all $n$ we have $A_n>c$, c is also the infimum then for every $\varepsilon>0$ we have $N\in\mathbb N$ such that: $a_m<c+\varepsilon$ for all $N<m$

Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: no I'm still having trouble I just have no clue what to do

Comment: In what way is what James wrote different or any less relevant that what you explain, JonesY ? The introduction of the quantification on $\epsilon$ is somewhat unusual, but not wrong, and the final statement is indeed the true definition of the limit of a sequence in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS it's a fine point.
from the decreasing  of the sequence and the existence of $N$ we conclude that for every $N<m$ we have $|a_n -c|<\varepsilon$. He didn't conclude that, it was added to his answer later. Don't forget he is just starting to study math, this is the point u can't assume yet he knows the basics.